# Connect Azure Data Marketplace to SQL Server 2008 R2

Tags: azure, sql-server-2008-r2, azure-marketplace

Is there a way to connect SQL Server 2008 R2 to the Azure Data Marketplace to enable data import?

Are there any ODBC or JDBC drivers for the Azure Data Marketplace?

Answer (score 0):

I'm a bit confused by the question. Is this about publishing data through the Windows Azure Marketplace and sourcing it from SQL Server? Or is it about accessing published data from an application and bringing that data into your own app?

**If the former:** 
You may choose to host your data in SQL Server. When you sign up for data hosting in the Windows Azure Marketplace, you'll provide the requisite connection strings for your servers. You don't have to worry about ODBC/JDBC drivers. See the [data publishing documentation](https://datamarket.azure.com/publishing) for more details.

**If the latter:** Data may be accessed via HTTP/OData, not ODBC/JDBC. It's a metered consumption model, so you need to subscribe to a particular data feed, which then gives you an access token. Check out [this video](http://channel9.msdn.com/Events/TechEd/NorthAmerica/2011/COS307) from TechEd last year to see more about this, along with a .NET code sample. You can easily access data from any other language as well.

If your goal is to access the data feed directly from SQL Server: I'm no expert in CLR Stored Procedures, but if CLR SP's supported code that can access a web service endpoint, I guess you could write a CLR SP to access a data feed, pull data down, and populate local tables. I have no idea if this is supported or advisable...